# Deleting Lines of a Plot Which has Plotted with axvspan()

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive-mode

I am doing some animating plots with `ion()`function. I want to draw and delete some lines. I found out `axvspan()` function, I can plot the lines and shapes with it as I want. But as long as I am doing an animation I also want to delete that lines and shapes. I couldn't find a way to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the necessary functions. I used `dir()` function to find methods. `axvspan()` returns a `matplotlib.patches.Polygon` result. This type of data has `set_visible` method, using it as `x.set_visible(0)` I removed the lines and shapes.